# How to set proxy for different API server using Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

So I have 2 applications:

1. an Adonis API server accessible via `http://10.10.120.4:3333`
2. A SSR app using Nuxt.js accessible via `http://10.10.120.4:80`

The Nuxt.js app is accessible outside using url `http://my-website.com`. I have axios module with this config

```
axios: {
    baseURL: '0.0.0.0:3333/api',
    timeout: 5000
}
```

Now the problem is, when I am requesting data with *asyncData* it works, but when the request was made from outside `asyncData`, say `created()` for example, it throws an error saying the url `http:0.0.0.0:3333` is missing which is true since it's already running in the browser and not in the server.

The first solution that I've tried is to change the `baseURL` of the axios module to this

```
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://my-website.com/api',
    timeout: 5000
}
```

But it seems nuxt server can't find it, so I think the solution is to make proxy and installed [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module).

And this is my proxy config in `nuxt.config.js`

```
{
  proxy: {
    '/api': 'http://my-website.com:3333',
  }
}
```

and then I just changed my axios baseURL to

```
http://my-website.com/api
```

But again it didn't work.

My question is, how do you deal with this kind of scenario? Accessing different server from browser?

Answer (score 24):

When using Proxy in a nuxt project you need to remove baseUrl and set proxy to true as seen below.

```
axios: {
  // Do away with the baseUrl when using proxy
  proxy: true
},
proxy: {
  // Simple proxy
  "/api/": {
    target: "https://test.com/",
    pathRewrite: {"^/api/": ""}
  }
},
```

when making a call to your endpoint do:

```
// append /api/ to your endpoints
const data = await $axios.$get('/api/users');
```

checkout Shealan [article](https://accidental.dev/author/shealan/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have **cors policy error** one of simple ways is you can use the proxy feature on your project.
suppose you use from the **axios** module and your url server is like below:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/index
```

at the first you should add the **axios** and **proxy** config in the **nuxt.config.js** file:

```
modules: [
'@nuxtjs/axios',
'@nuxtjs/proxy'
],
axios: {
proxy: true
},
 proxy: {
"/api": {
  target: "http://localhost:8081",
  pathRewrite: { "^/api": "/api" },
  changeOrigin: true
}
},
```

then you add this code like this for request or whatever you want:

```
methods: {
async show() {
  this.$axios.get('/api' + '/v1/index')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("this is error")
    })
}
}
```

**NOTICE:** if you want to read the base url from **.env** file,
change the **"http://localhost:8081"** with **process.env.BASEURL**:

```
proxy: {
"/api": {
  target: process.env.BASEURL,
  pathRewrite: { "^/api": "/api" },
  changeOrigin: true
}
},
```

then create the **.env** file in root project inside the **nuxt.config.js**, next write this code on it:

```
BASEURL=http://localhost:8081
```